# Passing a serialized array using POST yields unexpected result

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array, deserialization

I am puzzled.

My goal is to pass the array through POST to another page and access it's data.  I found a way of doing it using serialize().

It worked fine since I am able to see the array on the other page, but when I try to access a nested array within the main array I don't get the expected results. In other words, I can access the data inside the main array but I get "null" for the inner array.

Let me show you what I did:

```
//The array:
    $cart = &JModelLegacy::getInstance('cart', 'jshop'); 
    $cart->load(); 

//I can access data of the inner array (the products) within the $cart array, for example:
    $productos = $cart->products;
    echo "<pre>".json_encode($cart, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";        
    echo "<pre>".json_encode($productos[1], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";        

//Then serializing it:
    $serializedcart = serialize($cart);

//Then sending it in a form using POST
    <input type='hidden' name='cartserialized' value='<?php print $serializedcart?>'>
```

.... then on the other page:

```
// I unserialize the transferred array:
$carretilla = unserialize($_POST[cartserialized]);

// And this doesn't work anymore, I get "null" for $productos:
$productos = $carretilla->products;
echo "<pre>".json_encode($carretilla, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";      
echo "<pre>".json_encode($productos[1], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";
```

Why? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is the output before serialization: (Output of $cart and products inside cart.)

`{
    "type_cart": "cart",
    "products": [
        {
            "quantity": 1,
            "product_id": 329,
            "category_id": "17",
            "tax": null,
            "tax_id": "0",
            "product_name": "ATX Cromo Puro",
            "thumb_image": "thumb_882-2.jpg",
            "delivery_times_id": "0",
            "ean": "882-2",
            "attributes": "a:1:{i:1;i:28;}",
            "attributes_value": [
                {
                    "attr_id": 1,
                    "value_id": 28,
                    "attr": "Color",
                    "value": "Cromo"
                }
            ],
            "extra_fields": [],
            "weight": "0.0000",
            "vendor_id": "1",
            "files": "a:0:{}",
            "freeattributes": "a:0:{}",
            "manufacturer": "Cross",
            "pid_check_qty_value": "A:218",
            "price": 570,
            "href": "\/index.php\/tienda\/product\/view\/17\/329",
            "free_attributes_value": []
        },
        {
            "quantity": 3,
            "product_id": 469,
            "category_id": "21",
            "tax": null,
            "tax_id": "0",
            "product_name": "Bater\u00eda Auxiliar",
            "thumb_image": "thumb_JK-PB035.jpg",
            "delivery_times_id": "0",
            "ean": "JK-PB035",
            "attributes": "a:0:{}",
            "attributes_value": [],
            "extra_fields": [],
            "weight": "35.0000",
            "vendor_id": "1",
            "files": "a:0:{}",
            "freeattributes": "a:0:{}",
            "manufacturer": null,
            "pid_check_qty_value": "P:469",
            "price": 265,
            "href": "\/index.php\/tienda\/product\/view\/21\/469",
            "free_attributes_value": []
        }
    ],
    "count_product": 4,
    "price_product": 1365,
    "summ": 0,
    "rabatt_id": 0,
    "rabatt_value": 0,
    "rabatt_type": 0,
    "rabatt_summ": 0,
    "model_temp_cart": "tempcart",
    "price_product_brutto": 1365
}
{
    "quantity": 3,
    "product_id": 469,
    "category_id": "21",
    "tax": null,
    "tax_id": "0",
    "product_name": "Bater\u00eda Auxiliar",
    "thumb_image": "thumb_JK-PB035.jpg",
    "delivery_times_id": "0",
    "ean": "JK-PB035",
    "attributes": "a:0:{}",
    "attributes_value": [],
    "extra_fields": [],
    "weight": "35.0000",
    "vendor_id": "1",
    "files": "a:0:{}",
    "freeattributes": "a:0:{}",
    "manufacturer": null,
    "pid_check_qty_value": "P:469",
    "price": 265,
    "href": "\/index.php\/tienda\/product\/view\/21\/469",
    "free_attributes_value": []
}`

And after serialization and sending:

`{
    "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name": "jshopCart",
    "type_cart": "cart",
    "products": [
        {
            "quantity": 1,
            "product_id": 329,
            "category_id": "17",
            "tax": null,
            "tax_id": "0",
            "product_name": "ATX Cromo Puro",
            "thumb_image": "thumb_882-2.jpg",
            "delivery_times_id": "0",
            "ean": "882-2",
            "attributes": "a:1:{i:1;i:28;}",
            "attributes_value": [
                {
                    "attr_id": 1,
                    "value_id": 28,
                    "attr": "Color",
                    "value": "Cromo"
                }
            ],
            "extra_fields": [],
            "weight": "0.0000",
            "vendor_id": "1",
            "files": "a:0:{}",
            "freeattributes": "a:0:{}",
            "manufacturer": "Cross",
            "pid_check_qty_value": "A:218",
            "price": 570,
            "href": "\/index.php\/tienda\/product\/view\/17\/329",
            "free_attributes_value": []
        },
        {
            "quantity": 3,
            "product_id": 469,
            "category_id": "21",
            "tax": null,
            "tax_id": "0",
            "product_name": "Bater\u00eda Auxiliar",
            "thumb_image": "thumb_JK-PB035.jpg",
            "delivery_times_id": "0",
            "ean": "JK-PB035",
            "attributes": "a:0:{}",
            "attributes_value": [],
            "extra_fields": [],
            "weight": "35.0000",
            "vendor_id": "1",
            "files": "a:0:{}",
            "freeattributes": "a:0:{}",
            "manufacturer": null,
            "pid_check_qty_value": "P:469",
            "price": 265,
            "href": "\/index.php\/tienda\/product\/view\/21\/469",
            "free_attributes_value": []
        }
    ],
    "count_product": 4,
    "price_product": 1365,
    "summ": 0,
    "rabatt_id": 0,
    "rabatt_value": 0,
    "rabatt_type": 0,
    "rabatt_summ": 0,
    "model_temp_cart": "tempcart",
    "price_product_brutto": 1365
}
null`

Comment: Have you validated that $_POST[cartserialized] has content on the other page before you attempt to unserialize it?

Comment: Use the var_dump, check if you just did a shallow copy, or a deep copy on your object serialization.

Comment: Yes. it has data as you can see on the output (question edited). And the only difference is an aditional key(value) "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name" that I don't know where it came from..  And as for shallow copy or deep copy.. I have no idea what you're talking about Bonatti.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deserialize an object in PHP, you need to load the class first. So include the script that defines the type of this object, then deserialize.

Comment: For further reference, see [Object Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.

I tried using json_encode and json_decode as suggested in other forum and it seems to work better and I have no problem sending and retrieving the data on the other end.

Thanks for your valuable time.